# Is is possible to performa group by taking in all the fields in aggregate?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am on apache spark `3.3.2`. Here is a sample code

```
val df: Dataset[Row] = ???

df
 .groupBy($"someKey")
 .agg(collect_set(???)) //I want to collect all the columns here including the key.
```

As mentioned in the comment I want to collect all the columns and not have to specify all the columns again. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Somekey are any specific key that you will hard code or all the columns ? and how you want to collect all the  columns as a Json or comma separated ? Please update question with these details and also it will be good if you can attached sample table and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to aggregate all elements that match the same key as a list of json objects you can perform something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
      ("steak", "1990-01-01", "2022-03-30", 150),
      ("steak", "2000-01-02", "2021-01-13", 180),
      ("fish",  "1990-01-01", "2001-02-01", 100)
    )).toDF("key", "startDate", "endDate", "price")

df.show()

df
 .groupBy("key")
 .agg(collect_set(struct($"*")).as("value"))
 .show(false)
```

output:

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
|  key| startDate|   endDate|price|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
|steak|1990-01-01|2022-03-30|  150|
|steak|2000-01-02|2021-01-13|  180|
| fish|1990-01-01|2001-02-01|  100|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+

+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|key  |value                                                                       |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|steak|[{steak, 1990-01-01, 2022-03-30, 150}, {steak, 2000-01-02, 2021-01-13, 180}]|
|fish |[{fish, 1990-01-01, 2001-02-01, 100}]                                       |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.columns` to access the list of columns of your dataframe. Then you can process it to generate the list of aggregations you want:

```py
# let's say that you want to group by "someKey", and collect the values
# of all the other columns.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
result = df\
    .groupBy("someKey")\
    .agg(*[F.collect_set(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != "someKey"])
```

NB: You may remove `if c != "someKey"` in case you want to collect the `someKey` column as well.

In scala, the `agg` function signature is as follows:

> `def agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): DataFrame`

Therefore, we cannot unpack a list directly but there is a simple workaround:

```scala
val aggs = df.columns
    .map(c => collect_set(c) as c)
    .filter( _ != "someKey") // optionnaly
val result = df.groupBy("someKey").agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail : _* )
```